# Can't pass secret environment variable to Dockerfile

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

I created a simple docker-compose.yml and dockerfile to debug the issue.
.env file:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgre...."
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8080:8000'
    env_file:
      - .env
    entrypoint: echo "Hush! This is a secret '$DATABASE_URL'"
```

Dockerfile:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10-slim-bullseye

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}
ENV DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL
RUN echo DATABASE_URL:  ${DATABASE_URL}
```

Running docker compose, echo doesn't show the secret url:

```
% docker compose up
[+] Building 1.2s (7/7) FINISHED 
....
=> [web 2/2] RUN echo DATABASE_URL:   
deploy-impact-23-kpi-4-web-1  | Hush! This is a secret 'postgresql://p......'
deploy-impact-23-kpi-4-web-1 exited with code 0
```

docker compose config output:
...

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      ........
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    entrypoint:
      - echo
      - Hush! This is a secret 'postgresql://postgres:T......'
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgr....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not just use any environment variables from the host environment in a `Dockerfile` but [only the ones you already defined](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) within the `Dockerfile` with an [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) directive.

To pass [build-time variables to `docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-arg) you have to use [`ARG`s](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg).
But you can use `docker compose` to pass host environment variables via [interpolation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/12-interpolation/) as [build `args`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#args):

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        DATABASE_URL: $DATABASE_URL
    ports:
      - '8080:8000'
    env_file:
      - .env
    entrypoint: echo "Hush! This is a secret '$DATABASE_URL'"
```

```docker
# Dockerfile
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10-slim-bullseye

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}
ARG DATABASE_URL
RUN echo DATABASE_URL:  ${DATABASE_URL}

# if you want to make the value available as environment variable
# to processes in the container, keep this line
ENV DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL
```

---

But as [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) correctly noted in the comment below using the `$DATABASE_URL` while building might be the wrong approach (depending on your needs):

- if it is not actually needed **while** building you should rather use a run-time environment variable with `docker run -e DATABASE_URL=...` - so you don't have to rebuild the image everytime the value changes/for different environments
- if the value contains a *secret* you should not use `ENV` or `ARG` as this stores the value in plain text in the image! You should rather use [`docker secret`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) (which you can also use [while building](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypesecret))

Comment: (Remember that `docker inspect` will show the variable value in plain text, and with this approach you'd have to rebuild the image if the database location ever changed, for example because you're using a hosted non-container database in production.  I might not put this in an `ARG`.)

Comment: Oh yes, that's absolutely correct. I focused only on the "how to pass a value to be baked into an image" part and overlooked the actual use case. I updated my answer to include best practices.